# Capital letter after colon, in list?

Tags: capitalization

So I'm going through a list of reasons to choose something, followed by a semicolon and then an explanation.

- Aerodynamic resistance: The reason that this is important is bla bla bla...

vs

- Aerodynamic resistance: the reason that this is important is bla bla bla...

Is the first word after the colon capitalized?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capitalization after use of colon?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/32649/capitalization-after-use-of-colon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention a 'semicolon' but then (correctly) use a colon.

A colon is nearly always preceded by a complete sentence; what follows the colon may or may not be a complete sentence, and it may be a mere list or even a single word.

British usage: no capital letter after a colon unless it is to start a proper noun or acronym.

American usage: a capital letter if the text after the colon is a complete sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Michael Harvey's answer is quite comprehensive. Additionally, you may put a period between both parts, and if they represent two full independent sentences, you can use a colon and start the second part with a capital letter. I meet this type of spelling most often.